# How to align widgets inside a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to align my widgets at the start and at the end of row and I am not able to acheive so? I am confused what to do

doing padding is a static solution and it is giving the overflow error in some devices I want to acheive it for generic all device I dont know how to do.

Kindly help

```
Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:60,left:30,right:30),child:
  Row(
    children: <Widget>[                    
       Cancel_btn,
       Retry_btn
     ],
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minimal amount of code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // magic is here
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(child: Text('Cancel'), onPressed: () {}),
              RaisedButton(child: Text('Retry'), onPressed: () {}),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it.

(I) Using `mainAxisAlignment`.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // add this
  children: [
    Child1(),
    Child2(),
  ]
)
```

(II) Using `Spacer()`.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Child1(),
    Spacer(), // or add this
    Child2(),
  ]
)
```